# Running example app of jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu

Tags: android, slide, slidingmenu

I'm new to Android and I'm having trouble running the example of jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu Library on Android.
Since I have dependencies to the ActionBarSherlock project and the library itself, Eclipse does not know which R to use for the ids.
I get the following error messages:

1)The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type ResponsiveUIActivity must override or implement a supertype method (although I imported the ABS classes)

2)R cannot be resolved to a variable (about 20 such messages)

3)The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type BaseActivity

4)The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (MenuItem)

I included both ABS and the SlidingMenu library to the Build path and imported both libraries at the Properties>Android section. Project Build target is Android 4.2.2, minSdkVersion = 8, targetSdkVersion=17.

Any ideas how to fix these issues?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it.
Just import the R file from the sliding menu package
and go to the SlidingFragmentActivity in the SlidingMenu library and make it extend SherlockFragmentActivity